# Problem extracting Youtube search results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and have learned basis of Web Scraping with bs4. here i tried to extract all the links of Youtube search results , it doesn't work like on other sites. i analyzed the search result html data and the links of search results were in anchor tag with id "video title" , but the tag doesn't appear in my bs4 parsed html document

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
name=input("Enter video name ")
url='https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+name
searched=requests.get(url)
soup=bs(searched.text,'html.parser')
aid=soup.find_all('a',{'id':'video-title'})
print(aid)
```

i expect the output contain all the search result.
i have not learned other packages , i want to do this in bs4 if possible.

Comment: this is a pretty common question on StackOverflow  (and in the tags you have) so there should be lots of info to help you with this.

Comment: the only answers out there is of selenium or api. selenium makes everything slow and pops up and i dont like it.is there any selenium like browser that works completely in background invisible.?? i was just asking if bs4 could do these things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All this trouble to get YouTube search result data is just a waste of time and effort.

Why not try out these options

- [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)
- [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) + [Headless chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

That being said, for the first 20 results, you can get the data from the JavaScript content in the source. The answer to that is given below.

After about 1 hr of making sense of the resulting json, it still fails for some queries.YouTube is a very complicated site. The response may vary based on location, browser, search query etc.

We are extracting the data from this script tag in the source.
[image]

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re
import json
headers={
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}
name=input("Enter video name: ")
url='https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hello'+name
searched=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=bs(searched.text,'html.parser')
aid=soup.find('script',string=re.compile('ytInitialData'))
extracted_josn_text=aid.text.split(';')[0].replace('window["ytInitialData"] =','').strip()
video_results=json.loads(extracted_josn_text)
#print(item_section=video_results["contents"]["twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer"]["primaryContents"]["sectionListRenderer"]["contents"][1])
item_section=video_results["contents"]["twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer"]["primaryContents"]["sectionListRenderer"]["contents"][0]["itemSectionRenderer"]["contents"]

for item in item_section:
    try:
        video_info=item["videoRenderer"]
        title=video_info["title"]["simpleText"]
        url=video_info["navigationEndpoint"]["commandMetadata"]["webCommandMetadata"]["url"]
        print('Title:',title)
        print('Url:',url, end="\n----------\n")
    except KeyError:
            pass
```

Output:

```
Enter video name: hello
Title: New Punjabi Songs 2017-Hello Hello(Ful Song)-Prince Narula-Yuvika Chaudhary-Latest Punjabi Song 2017
Url: /watch?v=mv326-zVpAQ
----------
Title: Alan Walker - The Spectre
Url: /watch?v=wJnBTPUQS5A
----------
Title: Hello Hello (Full HD) - Rajvir Jawanda | MixSingh | Josan Bros | New Punjabi Songs 2018
Url: /watch?v=xydupjQSj44
----------
Title: Bachchan - Hello Hello - Kannada Movie Full Song Video | Sudeep | Bhavana | V Harikrishna
Url: /watch?v=oLMMgoug4Uk
----------
Title: Hello Hello latest 2017 16 june punjabi song
Url: /watch?v=MqCSsPXw8QU
----------
Title:   Hello Hello   | + More Kids Songs | Super Simple Songs
Url: /watch?v=saDkICxEdgY
----------
Title: 'Gallan Goodiyaan' Full VIDEO Song | Dil Dhadakne Do | T-Series
Url: /watch?v=jCEdTq3j-0U
----------
Title: Hello Hello Gippy Grewal Feat. Dr. Zeus Full Song HD | Latest Punjabi Song 2013
Url: /watch?v=IRW2O4QZhgs
----------
Title: Hello Hello | Pataakha | Malaika Arora | Vishal Bhardwaj & Rekha Bhardwaj | Gulzar | Ganesh Acharya
Url: /watch?v=RxBAitQLSLA
----------
Title: Hello Hello (Lyrical Audio) Prince Narula ft. Yuvika Chaudhary | Punjabi Lyrical Audio 2017 | WHM
Url: /watch?v=v8VIsIvhDoQ
----------
Title: Hello Hello Full Video Song || Bhale Bhale Magadivoi || Nani, Lavanya Tripathi
Url: /watch?v=y3FI02OO_kU
----------
Title: Hello hello gaad bahe dhufee na egaa  (new comedy hhhhhh)
Url: /watch?v=DuRrcTo4rgg
----------
Title: Proper Patola - Official Video | Namaste England | Arjun | Parineeti | Badshah | Diljit | Aastha
Url: /watch?v=YmXJp4RtBCM
----------
Title: Official Video: Nikle Currant Song | Jassi Gill | Neha Kakkar | Sukh-E Muzical Doctorz | Jaani
Url: /watch?v=uBaqgt5V0mU
----------
Title: Insane (Full Song)  Sukhe - Jaani - Arvindr Khaira - White Hill Music - Latest Punjabi Song 2018
Url: /watch?v=mKpPhVVF8So
----------
Title: Radha bole HELLO HELLO-cartoon song mix with step up 2
Url: /watch?v=TFCTgNCzrck
----------
Title: Hello Song | CoCoMelon Nursery Rhymes & Kids Songs
Url: /watch?v=fxVMqaViVaA
----------
Title: Bachchan - Hello Hello Unplugged Version | Sudeep | Bhavana | V Harikrishna
Url: /watch?v=lvH3kTGJeEQ
----------
Title: Hello Hello! Can You Clap Your Hands? | Original  Kids Song | Super Simple Songs
Url: /watch?v=fN1Cyr0ZK9M
----------
```

One last thing that you can try out is to emulate the API used by youtube itself

ie. POST request to

[https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=yoursearchtext](http://Request%20URL:%20https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hello)

It has a lot of cookie and session values being sent as parameters.  You may need to emulate all of them. You may need to use [Requests session objects](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) to do that.

Comment: thanks mate, you actually did it without using selenium or API  just as i wanted, but this makes things difficult and maybe not possible in every dynamic sites , so i will be using Selenium even though it is RAM and time consuming..thanks again

Comment: very nice, how can i use this for a .html or .php website? @Bitto